# How to copy files from multiple subfolders(unknown names) to one folder using Robocopy?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I want to copy multiple files (specific files) from multiple subfolders to one folder. The problem is that I don't know the names of subfolders because they are dynamically created by server.

I don't want to copy the subfolders itself, but copy the files inside these subfolders ONLY.

Comment: how about `robocopy`s `/s` switch?

Comment: @Stephan it only copy subdirectories, but i want to copy the files inside these subdirectories NOT subdirectories itself.

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy` can't do that. Use a simple `copy` command with a loop:

```
for /r "X:\Source\" %%a in (*) do ECHO copy /b "%%a" "Z:\Destination\"
```

NOTE: I disarmed the `copy` command by just echoing it. When it does, what you want, just remove the `ECHO`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "source=C:\Folder_Source"
SET "dest=C:\Destination"
SET "FileList=*.pdf" 

SET "dupCnt=1"

FOR /R "%source%" %%A IN (%FileList%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%%~NXA" (
        XCOPY /F /Y "%%~FA" "%dest%\" && IF EXIST "%%~FA" DEL /Q /F "%%~FA"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :DupeRoutine "%%~FA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
        )
    )
GOTO :EOF

:DupeRoutine
IF EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" (
    SET /A dupCnt=%dupCnt%+1
    CALL :DupeRoutine "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~1" "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" && DEL /Q /F "%~1"
    SET "dupCnt=1" 
    )
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find all of the files and copy them to a single directory. When you are confident that the correct files are being processed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` command. Your directories will be different than mine.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path 'C:\src\t' | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\datatarget' -WhatIf }
```

If you are willing to use aliases, it can be shorter.

```
gci -rec -file -path 'C:\src\t'|%{cp $_.FullName 'C:\datatarget' -WhatIf}
```

If you must run it from a cmd.exe shell, use the following.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "gci -rec -file -path 'C:\src\t'|%{cp $_.FullName 'C:\datatarget' -WhatIf}"
```